# Picking element from the list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform an element containing a serialized comma separated list into individual XML elements, selecting list elements with a particular prefix. The first component of the resulting list should be output as an element distinct from the other ones.
For example,

```
<source>xxx-22-33, aa-11-11, aa-22-22, aa-33-33</source>
```

should be transformed into

```
<ref>aa-11-11</ref>
<xref>aa-22-22</xref>
<xref>aa-33-33<xref>
```

I came up with the following template for a partial solution but got stumped picking up the first list element for a particular treatment. Any suggestions? TIA.

```
    <xsl:template name="xrefs">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($list, ', ')">
            <xsl:variable name="el" select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="starts-with($el, 'aa-')">
                <xsl:element name="cve-id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$el"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show a full XSLT stylesheet, not only a snippet. Especially the template where the `xrefs` template is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show the definition of the template where the `xrefs` template is invoked. But I can give you a solution without a named template, i.e. a full stylesheet that works on its own.

The interesting part of the stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:variable name="element-name" select="if (position() = 1) then 'ref' else 'xref'"/>
```

where we make use of XPath 2.0's abilities with conditional results. The variable definition must needs be inside the `for-each` that tokenizes the text content of the `source` element, because the evaluation of the `position()` function depends on the context. In this case, we need the context to be one of those tokens.

I am further applying `normalize-space()` to the tokens, since whitespaces will remain after tokenizing if there are any.

---

Also, it is worth noting that my approach makes specific assumptions about the nature of your data - which you have not explained comprehensively. In particular, I am assuming that it is always the first token in the list that should be treated differently, as opposed to treating differently a token with a certain content that happens to be the first item by accident (as your attempted solution somehow seems to indicate).

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
            <xsl:variable name="element-name" select="if (position() = 1) then 'ref' else 'xref'"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ref>xxx-22-33</ref>
<xref>aa-11-11</xref>
<xref>aa-22-22</xref>
<xref>aa-33-33</xref>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and your assumption about the first list element is correct. And also thanks for the normalize-space() - good to know